# Integration with probability density function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

A probability density function is given by

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
ax^{2}e^{-bx^{2}} &x\geq0 \\ 
 0&x\lt0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Find a in terms of b.

---

So far I have

$a\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{2}e^{-bx^{2}}$ = 1

I was thinking maybe integration by parts? The formula is $\int$udv = uv - $\int$vdu , i'm just not sure what should be v and what should be dv etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate by parts to see \begin{align*} 
\int^\infty_0 x \cdot x e^{-bx^2} dx &= \left[ -\frac{x}{2b} e^{-bx^2} \right]^{x\to\infty}_{x = 0} + \frac{1}{2b} \int^\infty_0 e^{-bx^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{4b^{3/2}}.
\end{align*} Thus we need $a = \frac{4b^{3/2}}{\sqrt \pi}$ in order to make the integral $1$.

EDIT: to see how to do the integral $$\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}dx,$$ you can use the typical polar coordinates trick. Note that \begin{align*} \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}dx \right)^2 &= \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}dx\right)\left( \int_0^\infty e^{-by^2}dy \right) \\
&= \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 e^{-b(x^2+y^2)}dxdy \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int^\infty_0 e^{-br^2}r dr d\theta\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \left[ \frac{-1}{2b} e^{-br^2} \right]^{r\to\infty}_{r=0} = \frac{\pi}{4b}
\end{align*} which shows that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 \sqrt b}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts is an excellent approach. Using the formula $\int_a^b udv=[uv]_a^b-\int_b^avdu$ as you said (where in this case $a=0$ and $b=\infty$), you would want to make the integration as simple as possible. Since $e^{-bx^2}$ cannot be integrated by elementary methods, this is not a good choice for $dv$. However, $xe^{-bx^2}$ can be integrated by such methods, so one should choose $dv=xe^{-bx^2}dx$, which would mean $u=x$ and thus $du=dx$. Making a substitution $y=x^2$ we can change $xe^{-bx^2}dx$ to $\frac{1}{2}e^{-by}dy$ since $dy=2xdx$. Thus $v=\int\frac{1}{2}e^{-by}dy=\frac{-1}{2b}e^{-by}+c=\frac{-1}{2b}e^{-bx^2}+c$ where $c$ is just an arbitrary integration constant. The only remaining trick involves integrating $vdu$, which can be done by the double integral as shown in User8128's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible trick is to make use of the normal distribution if you are familiar with that.

$$ \begin{align} \int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-bx^2}dx 
&= \sqrt{2\pi\frac {1} {2b}}\int_0^{\infty}x^2\frac {1} {\sqrt{2\pi(1/2b)}}e^{-x^2/(2(1/2b))}dx \\
&= \frac {\sqrt{\pi}} {2\sqrt{b}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2\frac {1} {\sqrt{2\pi(1/2b)}}e^{-x^2/(2(1/2b))}dx \\
& = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}} {2\sqrt{b}} \frac {1} {2b} \\
& = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}} {4b^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$

The first equality is we figure out the integrand is proportional to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1/2b)$ and match the corresponding constant. The second equality is using the fact that the integrand is an even function. The third equality follows from the fact that $E[X^2] = Var[X]$ if $E[X] = 0$.